# Is the order of destructuring assignment in JavaScript guaranteed?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, language-lawyer

Is the order of destructuring assignments guaranteed to be left-to-right?  For example, in this code:

```
[ curItem.props, curItem ] = foo(curItem)
```

Where foo returns an array of two values.

Is the assignment to `curItem.props` guaranteed to happen prior to the assignment to `curItem`?

*According to my reading of the standard it does, but it's a hard standard to read..*

Comment: Just for the record, [here is the spec on destructuring assignment](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-destructuring-assignment). It...can be hard to read, yes.

Comment: Some of these tests via the spec seem to assume the order is guaranteed too. https://github.com/tc39/test262/blob/dfc7ecc6785e8adb4476ad77f4e0e6f62285bd62/implementation-contributed/v8/mjsunit/es6/destructuring-assignment.js

Comment: Sure, it compiles down to this: `var _a = foo(curItem), curItem.props = _a[0], curItem = _a[1];`

Comment: Yes it will happen prior to curItem

Comment: you have an array. what other order do you want?

Comment: ECMAScript does its best to totally avoid behavior that isn't 100% deterministic and specified, and mostly avoid implementation-defined behavior, so if you run something and it does what you want, there is a pretty good chance that it is doing that because the spec says so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is guaranteed by the [*Runtime Semantics: IteratorDestructuringAssignmentEvaluation*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-iteratordestructuringassignmentevaluation), specifically the production

```
AssignmentElementList: AssignmentElementList , AssignmentElisionElement
```

It first recursively evaluates the assignments on the left side of the target expression (until it reaches the empty list), then afterwards on the last element in the list (skipping elision elements). So in your example `[ curItem.props, curItem ]`, the `curItem.props` reference is evaluated and assigned to before the `curItem` reference.

It is however interesting to note that the entire expression on the left hand side of the `=` operator is evaluated *after* the right hand side when using destructuring syntax, in contrast to strictly left-to-right evaluation of normal assignment targets. In

```
[ curItem.props ] = foo(curItem)
```

the `curItem.props` reference is evaluated *after* the `foo` call, while in

```
curItem.props = foo(curItem)[0]
```

it is evaluated *before*. See [§12.15.4](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-assignment-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation).

Answer (score 0):

If you trust Babel to be spec-compliant, you can always [try verify things yourself](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=true&code_lz=NoAgxgrgTgkgLgUwLYDoAOUD2aDOAacaeZEAXRAF4QAzTTACklkSQEoBuAKCA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015-loose&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.9.0&externalPlugins=):

```
[ curItem.props, curItem ] = foo(curItem);
```

transpiles to

```
"use strict";

var _foo = foo(curItem);

curItem.props = _foo[0];
curItem = _foo[1];
_foo;
```

Comment: It may be spec-compliant yet the semantics still not guaranteed. For example, it could be undefined which order -- though I doubt that, since old languages got into trouble for not defining such things.

Comment: Also, the transpiled code you gave here is in fact a simplification, as the spec requires iterator usage.

Comment: Yes. This was in `loose` mode.